# Fade out previous :target after :target changed

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` that I want to be visible as :target using css. This is working fine so far. My problem is: I want it to be faded in and out.

My code:

```
<div id="stuff">
Content
</div>

#stuff {
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

#stuff:target {
    opacity:1;
}
```

So let's say on the following url it should fade in (what it does):

> example.com/example.htm#stuff

But when I change the url to the following (or anything else), it just becomes invisible without a transition:

> example.com/example.htm#

Note that I want to change the url by clicking on a link, not by modifing it via JavaScript.

My question is:

Is it possible to have a transition when changing the target for the previous target without the use of JavaScript? How would you accomplish it?

I do not want to use any JavaScript at all, if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just changed the value of the `opacity` property and it's working. As far as I know, `opacity` only accepts a decimal value between 0 and 1 (apart from `inherit`, `initial` and `unset`).

```css
#stuff {
    opacity:0;
    transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}

#stuff:target {
    opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="stuff">
Content
</div>
<a href="#stuff">Add hash</a>
<a href="#">Remove hash</a>
```

Comment: I should specify: I want it to happen when a link is clicked. `<a href="#stuff">enable</a><a href="#">disable</a>`. As I stated: No JavaScript, not even for the url-change.